# Remove the title, author from article but keep header

Tags: titles, titling

I want the title and date part to go away from the article. How do I do it? if I remove the `\maketitle` from the code, then the header also goes away but I want the header to stay. The doc content should start right after the header. Please note that I have used the `titling` package to create this header.

[image: Image of the pdf output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\topmargin -1.2in
\textheight 11in
\oddsidemargin -0.45in
\evensidemargin 0in
\textwidth 7in
\footskip 0.5in
\flushbottom

\renewcommand\maketitlehooka{%
    \setlength\parindent{0pt}%
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \begin{minipage}{.15\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[height=1.7cm]{st-logo}
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}{.7\textwidth}
            \centering
            Installation Sheet for OpenModelica-OpenIPSL\par
            OpenModelica Team\par
            FOSSEE, IIT Bombay
        \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.15\textwidth}
        \raggedright
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{FOSSEE-logo}
    \end{minipage}%
    \end{minipage}\vskip 2.5ex
    \par
    \hrule
}

\title{text}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    
    \section{The procedure to install OpenModelica-OpenIPSL on Windows OS}
    
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item To follow the installation procedure, you need to be connected to the internet.
        \item Open your default web browser.
        \item In the address bar, type the url: \url{https://www.openmodelica.org} and press Enter.
        \item Go to ``DOWNLOAD" tab.
        \item Select ``Windows".
        \item From ``Offcial Release", Click on 1.18.0 (32bit/64bit)
        \item From Parent Directory
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item If you are using a 64-bit system:
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item click on 64bit.
                \item Click on OpenModelica-v1.18.0-64bit.exe.
                \item Save OpenModelica-v1.18.0-64bit.exe file.
            \end{enumerate}
            \item If you are using a 32-bit system:
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item click on 32bit.
                \item Click on OpenModelica-v1.18.0-32bit.exe.
                \item Save OpenModelica-v1.18.0-32bit.exe file.
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{enumerate}
        \item Right Click on the downloaded file and select Run as Administrator.
        \item In Installation Pop-up window, click on Next.
        \item Choose the Destination Folder and click on Next.
        \item Click on Install.
        \item Click on Next.
        \item Click on Finish.
        \item OpenModelica is successfully installed.
        \item Again go to the default web browser and open a new tab.
        \item In the address bar, type the url: \url{https://github.com/OpenIPSL/OpenIPSL} and press Enter.
        \item Click on ``Download ZIP'' under green colored ``Code'' option.
        \item ``OpenIPSL-master.zip'' file will be downloaded.
        \item Now go to the folder where the file is downloaded, and extract the ``OpenIPSL-master.zip'' file to any desired location of your computer.
        \item Double-click on the folder ``OpenIPSL''. 
        \item  ``OpenIPSL'' folder contains the ``package.mo'' modelica file which needs to be opened with OMEdit to use the OpenIPSL library. 
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding your header to `\maketitle`, you could replace `\maketitle` with your header:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\topmargin -1.2in
\textheight 11in
\oddsidemargin -0.45in
\evensidemargin 0in
\textwidth 7in
\footskip 0.5in
\flushbottom

\renewcommand\maketitle{%
    \setlength\parindent{0pt}%
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \begin{minipage}{.15\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[height=1.7cm]{example-image-duck}
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}{.7\textwidth}
            \centering
            Installation Sheet for OpenModelica-OpenIPSL\par
            OpenModelica Team\par
            FOSSEE, IIT Bombay
        \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.15\textwidth}
        \raggedright
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    \end{minipage}%
    \end{minipage}\vskip 2.5ex
    \par
    \hrule
}

\title{text}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    
    \section{The procedure to install OpenModelica-OpenIPSL on Windows OS}
    
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item To follow the installation procedure, you need to be connected to the internet.
        \item Open your default web browser.
        \item In the address bar, type the url: \url{https://www.openmodelica.org} and press Enter.
        \item Go to ``DOWNLOAD" tab.
        \item Select ``Windows".
        \item From ``Offcial Release", Click on 1.18.0 (32bit/64bit)
        \item From Parent Directory
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item If you are using a 64-bit system:
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item click on 64bit.
                \item Click on OpenModelica-v1.18.0-64bit.exe.
                \item Save OpenModelica-v1.18.0-64bit.exe file.
            \end{enumerate}
            \item If you are using a 32-bit system:
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item click on 32bit.
                \item Click on OpenModelica-v1.18.0-32bit.exe.
                \item Save OpenModelica-v1.18.0-32bit.exe file.
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{enumerate}
        \item Right Click on the downloaded file and select Run as Administrator.
        \item In Installation Pop-up window, click on Next.
        \item Choose the Destination Folder and click on Next.
        \item Click on Install.
        \item Click on Next.
        \item Click on Finish.
        \item OpenModelica is successfully installed.
        \item Again go to the default web browser and open a new tab.
        \item In the address bar, type the url: \url{https://github.com/OpenIPSL/OpenIPSL} and press Enter.
        \item Click on ``Download ZIP'' under green colored ``Code'' option.
        \item ``OpenIPSL-master.zip'' file will be downloaded.
        \item Now go to the folder where the file is downloaded, and extract the ``OpenIPSL-master.zip'' file to any desired location of your computer.
        \item Double-click on the folder ``OpenIPSL''. 
        \item  ``OpenIPSL'' folder contains the ``package.mo'' modelica file which needs to be opened with OMEdit to use the OpenIPSL library. 
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Priyam You're welcome!